# jQuery - Multiple sorting with mixitup.js

Tags: jquery, sorting

I need to have this site's content sorting based on two indicators.
http://skarpsinn.no/dev/solstad/fleet/

So far I have both the alphabet and the category (psv,ahts, etc) working, but not together.

I don't know how to customize the script to work like this demo: http://mixitup.io/demos/parks

As of now it's just out of the box. 
Can anybody help out on this one?

Comment: I did not. MixItUp has now been updated, so it should be easier to do this, but I still cannot figure it out...